# How to move a tree?

Tags: tikz-pgf, forest

This is the tree I am drawing. I would like to move the left-facing brace (together with the x/y tree) closer to the m/n tree. When I try using "s sep", the p/b tree above also moves.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
    for tree={forked edge, anchor=center}
    [,phantom
        [,for tree={grow'=east}
            [, edge=rounded corners
                [text
                    [example text text text text
                        [example text, name=f1]
                        [example text]
                    ]
                    [example text, name=f2]
                    [example text]
                ]
                [text
                    [, edge=rounded corners
                        [m, text=red, name=f3]
                        [n, text=red]
                    ]
                    [, no edge
                        [example text, name=f4]
                        [example texts]
                    ]
                    [, edge=rounded corners
                        [text, name=f5]
                        [example text
                            [text]
                            [text]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
            [, edge=rounded corners
                [example text
                    [, edge=rounded corners
                        [text]
                        [text]
                    ]
                    [, edge=rounded corners
                        [example text]
                        [example text
                            [example text]
                            [example text]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
                [example text]
            ]
        ]
        [,for tree={grow'=west}, l=-42mm, s sep=0.5cm
            [, name=p1]
            [, name=p2]
        ]
        [,for tree={grow'=east}, l=-4.2cm
            [p]
            [b]
        ]
        [,for tree={grow'=west}, l=-2cm, s sep=0.5cm
            [, name=p3, edge=rounded corners, edge=red]
            [, name=p4, edge=rounded corners, edge=red]
        ]
        [, for tree={grow'=east}, l=-2cm
            [x, text=red, edge=red]
            [y, text=red, edge=red]
        ]
    ]
\draw[-] (f1) to (p2);
\draw[-] (f2) to (p1); 
\draw[-, red] (f3) to (p4); 
\draw[-, red] (f4) to (p3); 
\end{forest}

\end{document}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: [That’s quite easy](http://www.treesonwheels.com/files/images/IMG_7840_0.JPG).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  `xshift= <space>`.

[image: c]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
        for tree={forked edge, anchor=center}
        [,phantom
        [,for tree={grow'=east}
        [, edge=rounded corners
        [text1
        [example text text text text
        [example text, name=f1]
        [example text]
        ]
        [example text, name=f2]
        [example text]
        ]
        [text2
        [, edge=rounded corners
        [m, text=red, name=f3]
        [n, text=red]
        ]
        [, no edge
        [example text, name=f4]
        [example texts]
        ]
        [, edge=rounded corners
        [text, name=f5]
        [example text
        [text]
        [text]
        ]
        ]
        ]
        ]
        [, edge=rounded corners
        [example text
        [, edge=rounded corners
        [text]
        [text]
        ]
        [, edge=rounded corners
        [example text]
        [example text
        [example text]
        [example text]
        ]
        ]
        ]
        [example text]
        ]
        ]
        [,for tree={grow'=west}, l=-42mm, s sep=0.5cm
        [, name=p1]
        [, name=p2]
        ]
        [,for tree={grow'=east}, l=-4.2cm
        [p]
        [b]
        ]
        [,for tree={grow'=west}, l=-1.67cm, s sep=0.5cm, xshift=-5cm,% changed <<<<
        [, name=p3, edge=rounded corners, edge=green]
        [, name=p4, edge=rounded corners, edge=green]
        ]
        [, for tree={grow'=east, xshift=-5cm }, l=-1.67cm, % changed <<<<
        [x, text=red, edge=red]
        [y, text=red, edge=red]
        ]
        ]
        \draw[-] (f1) to (p2);
        \draw[-] (f2) to (p1); 
        \draw[-, red] (f3) to (p4); 
        \draw[-, red] (f4.east) to (p3); % changed <<<<
    \end{forest}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks, @Simon Dispa. Is there any way to have forest doing it automatically? Or do I need to use xshift everytime I want to specify the distance between trees?

Comment: @JJSilva I don't know. Should be. The forest document is pretty comprehensive, but I never fully explored it.

Comment: Anyaway, thanks a lot. This is exactly what I wanted.